# How to show multiple data points on same graph using Chart object using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

How can I plot 2 or more data points on the same Bar using Chart object?
I did try checking for a solution online, but could not make work.
Example: Total Students: 100, Girls = 40, Boys = 60.

So I want this data to show on Bar chart on each bar.

With my current code, it creates another bar for the Data point

Below is code I wrote so far.

```
    var chart = new Chart();
    chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(600);
    var area = new ChartArea();
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
    var series = new Series();

    series.Points.AddXY("Week1", 200);
    series.Points.AddXY("Week1", 100);
    series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

How can I make the above code look like the below image?

[image: Graph View]

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC and not Core MVC.Thank you

Comment: Removed the confusing tag in this case .....

Comment: done that already. Thank you

Comment: For MSChart this would be a StackedColumn chart type withe two series and 4 points each.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to MSChart will try to google StackedColumn chart and see if any sample code comes which I can test.

Comment: @TaW helped a lot, able to create stacked columns for Graph

Comment: Good! [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+StackedColumn+) from my posts

Comment: As far as I know, the MSChart is a web form control used in the asp.net WebForm. I suggest you could use some client chart library to render the data. Like [this](https://canvasjs.com/asp-net-mvc-charts/stacked-column-chart/)

Comment: chart.Series["Series 3"].Points.Add(new DataPoint
                {
                    AxisLabel = "Week1",
                    YValues = new double[] { ViewBag.HighErrorfirstWeek },
                    Color = Color.Firebrick,
                });  How can I show Color even if the value is 0? Kindly suggest